# Empty string being stored as null and need to differentiate between null and empty string in Orade

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, isnullorempty

I have a stored procedure which is receiving the data from an API.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
Demo_proc(Id in number,
          First_name in varchar2,
          Middle_name in varchar2,
          Last_name in varchar2)
```

This `middle_name` parameter can contain null as well as empty string but `first_name` and `last_name` parameters are not null. The data that is received from the API, I am directly storing into a database table `demo` which looks like this:

```
Create table Demo
(
    Id number primary key,
    First_name varchar2 (100),
    Last_name varchar2 (100),
    Middle_name varchar2 (100)
)
```

I have another stored procedure that is retrieving the data from the database table `Demo` and returning it to the API:

```
     Demo_ret(Id in number,
              P_demo_dtls sys_refcursor)
```

This `p_demo_dtls` will return `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`  columns from the `demo` table for the `Id` passed in as input.

The issue is since `middle_name` column contains null value even if API passes empty string, then it return null value through `demo_ret` procedure, because of which in API `middle_name` column is not getting displayed.

They want me to make changes in the database to differentiate between empty string and null value, sSuch that if they have passed an empty string in input they receive empty string in output via the `demo_ret` stored procedure.

Comment: Oracle doesn't distinguish between null and an empty string - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Nulls.html) - so you can't do anything in the table. You could store a magic value like `'(null)'` or a control character or something in place of nulls, *if you knew when to*; but your first procedure has no way of telling if an input parameter is meant to be an empty string or null, and your second procedure can't distinguish in its out ref cursor. The calls would have to pass/retrieve a magic value - which isn't ideal either...

Comment: So empty middle name is a thing now? If anything is in need of a fix, it's the application that accepts garbage.

Comment: Actually they have defined this is a valid use case where we can have empty string as middle_name. So have to make changes according to it.

Comment: You can add an explicit flag column to distinguish between null and an empty string middle_name.

Comment: This flag column will be populated by API? This will require change in the API code as well. Also this stored procedure can be called by multiple API so it will require code changes in all the API codes.

Comment: Even if you added code so that you could differentiate the two cases (@Serg's suggestion of a flag column would be the preferred method), the only way to pass that back to the caller would be to add a column to the result that differentiated between the two.  So you'd pass the caller a `NULL` middle name and then a separate column `is_middle_name_empty` that told them whether to treat the `NULL` middle name as `NULL` or as the empty string.  That would be... clunky at best.

Comment: @SurbhiSharma - yes, but there is no magic way for your procedure to know what was intended - something has to change for the caller to tell you. (Another option is to have a default value for that parameter as a magic value, and the caller omits that parameter for empty string, and includes it explicitly as null for null. But that's also clunky and painful; and doesn't fix the return value problem - returning different numbers of columns in the ref cursor would also be messy...)

Comment: If you are using `VARCHAR2` data types then empty strings `''` are identical to `NULL` and you cannot distinguish them. If you are using `CLOB` data types then you can store an empty string using `EMPTY_CLOB()` and it is not the same as `NULL`.